# Ruby on Rails response to POST via Android app

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, json, post

I have written a small RoR project with devise and scaffolding.
When registering new user via my desktop I get different result from when registering new user from my android app (using JSON).

Here is part of the source from the desktop:

```
<body>
<p class="notice">Welcome! You have signed up successfully.</p>
<p class="alert"></p>
.
.
```

And here is the response I get in my android app:

```
<body>
    <p class="notice"></p>
    <p class="alert"></p>
    .
    .
```

Why don't I get the notice? I know the app is working and the user has been created.

**Edit:** Maybe there is a way to configure Devise how to respond when registering via JSON? I don't need the html.. All I need is a confirmation..

**Edit2:** So now I added `httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");`
The user is created but my response is completely empty now. I need to figure how to make Devise create a JSON (custom?) response..

Comment: Put your controller and view code.

Comment: There is nothing to put. I Barely touched the code. It's all automagically created via scaffolding.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, all I needed was to add this:

```
respond_to :html, :json
```

to `gems/[Devise folder]/app/controllers/devise/registration_controller`

So it will be simpler just to add this line to devise_controller, so we will have JSON response in all the controllers.

```
# All Devise controllers are inherited from here.
class DeviseController < Devise.parent_controller.constantize
  include Devise::Controllers::ScopedViews
  respond_to :html, :json
.
.
.
```

In the android app, we need to remember:

```
httppost.setHeader("content-type", "application/json; charset= utf-8");
httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
```